# How to do cell iteration of excel in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am having an excel with 2 rows and 5 columns. Now I entered code manually to take values from 1st row. How can I iterate the process?

Below is the code for 1st row in excel. From the 2nd row on, I dont know how to do... I want to iterate one row after another.

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(
                               "\\C:\\users\\a-4935\\Desktop\\DataPool_CA.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
System.out.println("Reached to Sheet");
Cell a = sheet.getCell(2,1);
Cell b = sheet.getCell(3,1);
Cell c = sheet.getCell(4,1);
Cell d = sheet.getCell(5,1);
Cell e = sheet.getCell(6,1);
Cell f = sheet.getCell(7,1);
Cell g = sheet.getCell(8,1);
Cell h = sheet.getCell(9,1);
Cell i = sheet.getCell(10,1);

String uId              =   a.getContents();
String deptFromDat      =   b.getContents();
String deptToDate       =   c.getContents();
String dept1            =   d.getContents();
String arrival1         =   e.getContents();
String eihon1           =   f.getContents();
String branchCode1      =   g.getContents();
String userType1        =   h.getContents();
String sessionId1       =   i.getContents();
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the code below to iterate over all rows of a datasheet:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, use the following code:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    if(row == null) {
        //do something with an empty row
        continue;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        if(cell == null) {
            //do something with an empty cell
            continue;
        }
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: For the latter, be aware that getRow or getCell could return null! It's all [covered in the Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

Comment: @Gagravarr That's absolutely true, otherwise the next question is going to be 'Why do I have a NPE?'. Still, as the file OP referred to was supposed to have 2*5 cells *filled in*, I didn't include the checks. But for the sake of future readers, it's worth including them. Thanks!

Comment: *supposed to have* and *every file will have* are very rarely the same thing...!

Comment: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
this error is coming

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum (); ++i) {
        row=(Row) sheet.getRow(i);
        Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext())
        { .....
```

you can use the above code to iterate all rows and all cells

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change 1 to the row number, and use a for loop.
Based on your code you could do the following e.g. 
For exmaple:

```
for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
{

            Cell a = sheet.getCell(2,i);
            Cell b = sheet.getCell(3,i);
            Cell c = sheet.getCell(4,i);
...

}
```

Or better yet move the Cell declarations out of the for loop which is better practice.

```
Cell a,b, c...; 

for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
{

             a = sheet.getCell(2,i);
             b = sheet.getCell(3,i);
             c = sheet.getCell(4,i);
...

}
```

Comment: @user2314399 Did you change 1 to i?