# Apache POI - Iterating over columns in excel (XSSF)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I want to get my program to read an excel column from Top to Bottom, NOT left to right, like it is doing right now. Unfortunately, I cannot find anything in the documentation that lets me do this.

I have an excel file that looks like this:

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1    _        1      w
row2 | 3,2,7    _        2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     _        4      z
```

I'm writing some values (using XLWT) in column 2 that look like this:

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1  x,y,w      1      w
row2 | 3,2,7   y,x       2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     z        4      z
```

Essentially, column 3 and column 1 are being compared, and if cell (1,1) has values matched in column 3, column 4's values (which correspond to column 3) are written into column 2.

I've done this in Python actually, and I considered using Jython, however, I couldn't find any docs on importing python modules into Jython code. I believe XSSF apache-poi is the only way I can deal with xlsx files in java.

Relevant page: [How to do cell iteration of excel in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215750/how-to-do-cell-iteration-of-excel-in-java)

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class Expy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\...\\Bioactives25s.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<3; rowIndex++){
            XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex<3; columnIndex++){
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
                System.out.print(cell);.getCell(j);
               //iterates over cells
```

Again, mainly looking for a way to iterate through column values (top to bottom). I looked through the documentation: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

But I could only find code for dealing with rows and cells, not columns. I'd like to iterate through the columns though. Is there any code to deal with this?

Comment: A table column is an amount of cells with the same position in consecutive rows. Example: column `C:C` is `C1:Cn` is `.getRow(0).getCell(2)`, `.getRow(1).getCell(2)`, `.getRow(2).getCell(2)`, ... `.getRow(n).getCell(2)`.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily using the current API itself :

```
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex<3; columnIndex++){
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<3; rowIndex++){
        XSSFCell cell = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a null check to that - rows can be `null` if they've never had any data or styling put in them