# Spring boot api to calculate bulk students cgpa by uploading excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, file-upload, multipart

I developed an spring boot api to upload excel file  which contains many students marks , i wanted to calculated the each individual students cgpa and send it as a response but im getting null pointer exception while calculating cgpa.

please review my below code and help me where i was wrong.

**Service Class**

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<?> bulkCalculations(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
List<ResultCalculation> tempStudentList = new ArrayList<ResultCalculation>();
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for (int i = 1; i < worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  ResultCalculation tempStudent = new ResultCalculation();

  XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);

  tempStudent.setId((int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
  tempStudent.setStudentName(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
  tempStudent.setSubject1(row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue());
  tempStudent.setSubject2(row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
  tempStudent.setSubject3(row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
  tempStudent.setSubject4(row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
  tempStudent.setSubject5(row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue());
  tempStudent.setSubject6(row.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue());

  double totalMarks = row.getCell(2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7).getNumericCellValue();
  double percentage = totalMarks / 6;
  double cgpa = percentage / 9.5;
  // in above 3line calculations only i'm getting null pointer exception
  //  without this calculations excel file is extracting without any problem
  tempStudent.setCgpa(cgpa);
  tempStudentList.add(tempStudent);
 }
 return new ResponseEntity<Object>(tempStudentList, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

**Below is the excel file i am uploading **

[my excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRnOA.png)

please guide me how can i resolve this issue

**Without calculating cgpa i'm getting bellow response**

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"studentName": "Student1",
"subject1": 55,
"subject2": 64,
"subject3": 55,
"subject4": 56,
"subject5": 95,
"subject6": 46,
"cgpa": null
},
{
"id": 2,
"studentName": "Student2",
"subject1": 95,
"subject2": 54,
"subject3": 67,
"subject4": 85,
"subject5": 74,
"subject6": 56,
"cgpa": null
},
{
"id": 3,
"studentName": "Student3",
"subject1": 35,
"subject2": 76,
"subject3": 95,
"subject4": 67,
"subject5": 87,
"subject6": 79,
"cgpa": null
},
{
"id": 4,
"studentName": "Student4",
"subject1": 24,
"subject2": 84,
"subject3": 84,
"subject4": 56,
"subject5": 75,
"subject6": 55,
"cgpa": null
},
{
"id": 5,
"studentName": "Student5",
"subject1": 67,
"subject2": 55,
"subject3": 99,
"subject4": 74,
"subject5": 56,
"subject6": 55,
"cgpa": null
}
]
```

I wanted to include calculated cgpa in the above response

Comment: Did you check that totalMarks is returning a correct value? I think your `getCell()` is the issue, try another approach.

Comment: In total marks only I'm getting null pointer exception.  Can you suggest me other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `double totalMarks = row.getCell(2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7).getNumericCellValue();` you could try one of the following:

### For loop

```
double totalMarks=0;
for (int i=3;i<8;i++){
  totalMarks+= row.getCell(i).getNumericCellValue(); // Add cells to total marks one by one
}
//Other operations
```

### Iterator

```
double totalMarks=0;
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

while(cellIterator.hasNext())
{
  XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
  if(cell.getColumnIndex()>2)
  {
    totalMarks+=cell.getNumericCellValue();
  }
}
//Other operations
```

You could also adapt these two methods for the rest of your code if you wish.

#### References:

Mirnal - [SO: Iterating cells in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822741/apache-poi-iterating-over-columns-in-excel-xssf)
Kuldeeparya - [How to iterate xssf cells](https://kuldeeparya.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/how-to-iterate-xssf-excel-sheet-xlsx-using-apache-poi-apis/)