# How to retrieve the list of cells from first row using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to know how to iterate and get the list of cell values from excel file first row or specific row in a sheet using java with poi.

Could anyone please help me to know about this...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: google it before asking question.. http://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

Comment: someone please mark this as duplicate

Comment: @RamPrakash Why should you want to mark this question as duplicate. I need to know iterating the particular column cells. Do you have idea ?

Comment: Did you searched for answer to your question before asking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578535/get-cell-value-from-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do cell iteration of excel in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215750/how-to-do-cell-iteration-of-excel-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); // or: new XSSFWorkbook() - depending on excel version

Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
Row row = sheet.getRow(j);

Iterator iterator = row.cellIterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
     Cell cell = (Cell)iterator.next();

     // do whatever with cell...
}
```

Comment: What's that j value. You want me to specify j value as 0 to get the first row cell values

Comment: in Java, index values are usually denoted uding i,j etc. It's only a convention.

Comment: Judging from your questions, I would respectfully suggest that you  brush up on your basic Java skills, it might go a long way! :)

Comment: There are better answers for this in the duplicate question, or by looking at the apache POI quick guide https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator