# How to do a for loop only with rows and a fixed number of columns?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I have an application in Android that reads from an excel. I want to replace the while loop and put the for loop. I have only 3 columns so I think theres is another way to do this. Can you show me how to do this while loop with a for loop using only rows and 3 columns?

```
private void readExcelFile() {

        try{


            String inFileName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+"ola.xlsx";

            File file = new File(inFileName);
            Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(0);


            Iterator<Row> rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
//this is the loop I talked about
            while(rowIter.hasNext()){


                Row myRow =rowIter.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();


                while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                    Cell myCell = cellIter.next();





                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do cell iteration of excel in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215750/how-to-do-cell-iteration-of-excel-in-java)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16215750/2296441, and is also answered on the apache POI site here https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Comment: Tha does not solve the problem because my Cell class does not have getCell method.I need to use this exact form. So I need a different logic using the same variables that are present there

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Are you using POI? The answer mentioned above is how the Cell class in POI works.

Comment: What version of POI are you using?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "my Cell class". Did you write your own Cell class rather than using the one provided by Apache POI? If so, include it here.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: If any `java` question is tagged `android`, then you can forget all default Java knowledge and APIs. The language which `android` calls "Java" does share with default Java not much more as the same name. Definitelly the default `apache poi` API does not work in `android`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ... alternate looping logic using for loops
Sheet sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

for (int row = 0; row < sheet.getColumns(); row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < sheet.getRows(); column++) {
        Cell cell = sheet.getCell(column, row);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cellValue: " + cell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
 }
```

I looked into JExcel library, it has getRows & getColumns methods which return the no. of rows & columns respectively. Hence, I was able to iterate using for loops instead of using iterators.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Note that this will only work if there are no empty cells or rows

Answer (score 0):

Well it's more of algorithm than android you can loop through cells if you have row and column size:

```
int totalCount = rowSize * columnSize;
Iterator<Cell> rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
Iterator<Cell> cellIter;

for(int i = 0 ; i < totalCount ; i++){
    if(i % rowSize == 0){
        //Move to the Next Row
        myRow = rowIter.next();
        cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
    }

    Cell myCell = cellIter.next();
}
```

Though it may have a bug or two, but I think it will works like you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
String FilePath = "E://airline.xls";
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet2");
for(int row = 0; row < sh.getRows(); row++){
    for(int column = 0; column < sh.getColumns(); column++){
        System.out.print(sh.getCell(column, row).getContents() + "   ");
    }
}
```

I have done this using the JExcel library's workbook Class. Please have a look at the documentation at [blog]: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html/"JExcel Documentation".

The thing to note here is how **getCell** accepts the row and column parameters. If we pass these parameters the other way we will get Exception.