# How do I get column X and iterate over all of its rows?

Tags: java, excel, jsoup

There is a Microsoft Excel Online public spreadsheet. I need to iterate over all rows (1 to N) of column X and output their content. The difficulty is that I cannot figure out exactly how to iterate the rows by column. Unfortunately, I didn't find anything useful in the documentation. Point me on the right path, please.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do cell iteration of excel in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215750/how-to-do-cell-iteration-of-excel-in-java)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI https://poi.apache.org/ provides a good dependency for reading and writing to excels.
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/library/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/ has a basic tutorial for performing basic operations on excel files.

Comment: But this way required the excel file have been downloaded. I want parse online spreadsheet without downloading it